# Передача значений переменных из одного окна в другое=)

Tags: visual-basic

Как релизовать передачу значений переменных с одного программного окна в другое?
В Visual Basic 6.0 у каждого окна свой код, общих переменных по-моему создать не реально.

Сформулирую по-другому, если так мутно

Я создаю программу создающие таймеры(практика), в первом(главном) окне есть кнопка "Создать таймер", после открывается новое окно с параметрами нового таймера, которые нужно указать. 
Как передать значения вносимых ранее параметров в другое окно после нажатия "Готово" во втором окне?

Answer (score 1):

1) Создать класс, который будет хранить общие данные. При старте приложения создать глобальный объект этого класса. После этого доступ к объекту будет из всех окон (форм) приложения. Что-то вроде:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_Something As String

Public Property Get Something() As String
    Something = m_something
End Property
Public Property Let Something(ByVal value As String)
    m_something = value
End Property
```

2) Можно сделать общение средствами Windows API, а именно функциями

- FindWindow - поиск того окна, которое надо уведомить,
- SendMessage - посылка сообщения целевому окну

Можно вообще зарегистрировать свои собственные сообщения функцией RegisterWindowMessage.

3) Можно сохранять и читать настройки программы в реестр функциями [Registry API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx).